# Is there a way to remove the last character of a string in Python in O(1) time complexity?

Tags: python, string

Is there an easy way to remove the last character of a string in Python in O(1) time complexity? Would using  `string = string[:-1]` be O(1)?

Comment: No, you can't *remove characters from strings at all*. Strings in Python are *immutable*. You *always must create a new string*

Comment: Now, possibly, you could use a `bytearray`

Answer (score 5):

No, because strings are immutable. The *only* thing you can do is create a modified *copy* of a `str` value, which means copying all the characters you *don't* want to remove. Any such operation is inherently a O(n) operation.

`string[:-1]` doesn't remove the last character; it copies all *but* the last character.

Comment: Does `string[:-1]` create a slice?

Comment: @PeterWood I mean, it is using slice notation and it results in a new string.

Comment: Yes and no. `string[:-1]` is equivalent to `string[slice(None, -1, None)]`, which produces a new `str` object. It's the syntax inside the `[...]` that produces a `slice` object, but the result of the subsequent slicing operation is another `str`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Sorry, I wasn't thinking, of course it's materialised. I wonder whether there's an optimisation to use the original immutable string as backing. It would perhaps make sense.

Comment: @PeterWood it would be *possible*, I believe Go has slices that work like this generally, but at least in CPython, this isn't occuring.

Comment: In some sense, this is already an optimization. You trade the time it takes to create a new copy of the underlying character data for the complexity of sharing character data among multiple `str` objects.

Answer (score 1):

## Got some timing for you:

```
# Stright-forward
example_string = 'some medium string for examining the timing of 
different 
truncate methodes'
example_string = example_string[:-1]

# Stright-forward explicit
example_string = 'some medium string for examining the timing of 
different 
truncate methodes'
example_string = example_string[0:len(example_string)-1]

# Deleting last char
example_string = 'some medium string for examining the timing of 
different truncate methodes'
example_string = bytearray(example_string, encoding='utf-8')
del example_string[len(example_string)-1]
example_string = example_string.decode(encoding='utf-8')

# Creative way using replace (only valid if this word is unique in your string)
example_string = 'some medium string for examining the timing of different 
truncate methodes'
example_string = example_string.replace('methodes', "methode")
```

## Using timeit to execute all the above:

```
>>> print(f'{timeit.timeit(stmt=test_code)}\tStright-forward')
0.03856031800387427 Stright-forward
>>> print(f'{timeit.timeit(stmt=test_code)}\tStright-forward explicit')
0.07093821599846706 Stright-forward explicit
>>> print(f'{timeit.timeit(stmt=test_code)}\tDeleting last char')
0.34045136597706005 Deleting last char
>>> print(f'{timeit.timeit(stmt=test_code)}\tCreative way using replace (only valid if this word is unique in your string)')
0.07177364896051586 Creative way using replace (only valid if this word is unique in your string)
```